# Android 3.0 not working on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I installed the Android Studio 3.0 in my laptop. The OS is Windows 10, not an Insider build. After successful installation, when I open the Studio, it opens and after a while it stops working saying 'Android Studio stopped working'. I tried canary build and the issue is still the same. I installed Android Studio 2 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Uninstall Previous version of android Studio And Try android studio 3.0.1 from Its Official Site

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your version of android studio and install the last version with this link.

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html